# Java generic still forces type cast

Tags: java, generics

I'm finding that in a particular class structure my generic type appears to be prematurely erased. Here is the problem distilled as much as I can. Please consider these 3 classes:

Foo.java

```
import java.util.List;

public class Foo {

  public <V> V getFirst(List<V> list) {
    return (V) privateGetFirst(list);
  }

  private Object privateGetFirst(List list) {
    return list.get(0);
  }
}
```

Bar.java

```
import java.util.List;

public class Bar {
  private final Foo foo;

  public Bar() {
    foo = new Foo();
  }

  public <T> T getFirst(List<T> list) {
    return foo.getFirst(list);
  }
}
```

Baz.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Baz {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Bar bar = new Bar();
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("Hello World");

    String s = bar.getFirst(list);
  }
}
```

This is all good. However, if I define `Bar` as `public class Bar<V>` I'm suddenly forced to cast the return value of my call to `bar.getFirst`. The returned type of `bar.getFirst()` ends up being `Object` instead of `String`. Why?

Thanks for any help in understanding what's going on here.

**Update:**
If you want the actual code, I'm trying to add this method:

```
public <T> T invoke(final SerializableCallableIF<T> callable) {
  return vm.invoke(callable);
}
```

Here: https://github.com/apache/geode/blob/develop/geode-core/src/test/java/org/apache/geode/test/dunit/rules/MemberVM.java. When I invoke that method with a `SerializableCallable<String>` I don't want to have to cast it.

Comment: When you defined `Bar` to take a type parameter, did you remember to *provide* a type parameter?

Comment: Please post the code you have a question about instead of describing it indirectly and making us guess.

Comment: @user2357112 Ah! If I do `Bar<Object> bar = new Bar()` it works. Can you explain that?

Comment: Look up "raw types".

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
public class Bar<V> {
  private final Foo<V> foo;

  public Bar() {
    foo = new Foo<>();
  }

  public V getFirst(List<V> list) {
    return foo.getFirst(list);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You did not specify the type when calling `getFirst()`.

Try:

    `String s = bar.getFirst<String>(list);`

If you do not like it this way, consider declaring `T` as a class generics instead of on the method (see the other answer). It depends on your use c ase.

Comment: It's inferred in this case, not need to specify it.